# Finding $P(|Y|\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|X|)$ when $X,Y$ are i.i.d $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Let $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$ be two independent random variables.
>
> Find: $P(|Y|\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|X|)$

My way so far:

$P(|Y|\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|X|)=P(\sqrt{3}\cdot |Y|\ge |X|)=P(3Y^2\ge X^2)=P(\frac{3Y^2}{X^2}\ge 1)$

And since $X^2,Y^2\sim Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}), \frac{3Y^2}{X^2}\sim Beta(1.5,-1)$ but it's not possible because $-1<0$. 
Where is my mistake?

Comment: If we write $X+iY=Re^{i\Theta}$, then $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent and $\Theta\sim\operatorname{Uniform}[-\pi,\pi]$. In particular, $(X/R, Y/R)=(\cos\Theta,\sin\Theta)$ is uniformly distributed over the unit circle, and you can transform the probability in question to computing the (relative) length of the arc satisfying the condition. Consequently, the answer is $2/3$.

Comment: The other way: $X^2/Y^2$ is a square of r.v. with standard Cauchy distribution and $$P(X^2/Y^2\leq 3) = \int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}} \frac1\pi \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = 2/3.$$

Comment: @NCh This should be an answer IMO.

Comment: @StubbornAtom This could be the answer, if it was the shortest path. But the author in his solution focused on the distribution of the ratio of two squares, so I continued in the comment. If the author is not aware of the fact about the ratio of two normal distributions, this will be a long and inadequately difficult solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the ratio distribution of two gamma-square distributions, so let me go back to the basic. Since we know the joint distribution, as the form of p.d.f., we can simply write down the formula computing the probability in question as

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}\left(|Y| \geq \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|X|\right)
= \iint\limits_{|y|\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|x|} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
= \iint\limits_{|y|\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|x|} \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}

Now we see that both the domain of integration and the integrand have nice symmetry which can be easily described in terms of polar coordinates. So, applying the polar-coordinate $(x,y)=r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}\left(|Y| \geq \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|X|\right)
&= \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} re^{-r^2/2}\, \mathrm{d}r \right) \left( \int_{|\sin\theta|\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|\cos\theta|} \frac{1}{2\pi} \, \mathrm{d}\theta\right)  \\
&= \left[ -e^{-r^2/2} \right]_{r=0}^{r=\infty} \cdot \frac{\text{[length of the set $\{\theta \in [0, 2\pi] : |\tan\theta| \geq 1/\sqrt{3}\}$]}}{2\pi} \\
&= \frac{2}{3}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how do you came up with that equality between distributions.. I can offer a simpler answer just by decomposing the modules.

$|Y| > \frac{|X|}{\sqrt{3}}$ is

- $Y < \frac{X}{\sqrt{3}} $ if y < 0 and x < 0
- $Y > \frac{-X}{\sqrt{3}} $ if y > 0 and x < 0
- $-Y > \frac{X}{\sqrt{3}} $ if y < 0 and x > 0
- $Y > \frac{X}{\sqrt{3}} $ if y > 0 and x > 0

So you divided your problem in 4 simple probabilities

And for the law of total probablity:

$ P( |Y| > \frac{|X|}{\sqrt{3}} ) =$

$ P (Y < \frac{X}{\sqrt{3}} | ~ y < 0, x < 0) . P( y < 0, x < 0 ) + $

$P (Y > \frac{-X}{\sqrt{3}}| ~ y > 0 , x < 0) . P(y > 0 , x < 0) + $

$P (-Y > \frac{X}{\sqrt{3}} | ~ y < 0 , x > 0) . P(y < 0 , x > 0) + $

$P (Y > \frac{X}{\sqrt{3}} | ~ y > 0 , x > 0) . P (y > 0 , x > 0)) $

as each cuadrant has the same probability = 0.25

$ P( |Y| > \frac{|X|}{\sqrt{3}} ) = $

$P (Y < \frac{X}{\sqrt{3}} | ~ y < 0, x < 0) . 0.25 +$

$P (Y > \frac{-X}{\sqrt{3}}| ~ y > 0 , x < 0) . 0.25 +$

$P (-Y > \frac{X}{\sqrt{3}} | ~ y < 0 , x > 0) . 0.25 +$

$P (Y > \frac{X}{\sqrt{3}} | ~ y > 0 , x > 0) .0.25$

Its look messy, but it has a realy simple solution does not requires any transformation.

Comment: I was refering to the relation between the gamma and the  beta, and not as a critisism just because i could not found it

Comment: I have removed my comment.